# User Edit Profile Form won't edit all fields,Django

Tags: python, django

I have created a registration form using `Django's` `usercreation` form.
Then i created a `EditProfileForm` using the registration form.

My issue is that `EditProfileForm` uses `User Model`, and the Birthdate field is in `Profile Model`. Thus, I am able to edit all fields except Birthdate as it is not from the `User Model`.

How do I go about editing birthdate, or creating a form where I can edit all fields instead of only the user fields?

My Model for Profile:

```
class Profile(models.Model):
user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.PROTECT)

def __str__(self):
    return self.user.username;

USWEST = 'usw'
USEAST = 'use'
EUROPE = 'eu'
OCEANIA = 'oce'
ASIA = 'as'
SOUTHAMERICA = 'sam'
SOUTHAFRICA = 'saf'
MIDDLEEAST = 'me'

PREF_SERVER_CHOICES = (
    (USWEST, 'US-West'),
    (USEAST, 'US-East'),
    (EUROPE, 'Europe'),
    (OCEANIA, 'Oceania'),
    (ASIA, 'Asia'),
    (SOUTHAMERICA, 'South America'),
    (SOUTHAFRICA, 'South Africa'),
    (MIDDLEEAST, 'Middle-East'),
)

pref_server = models.CharField(
    max_length=3,
    choices=PREF_SERVER_CHOICES,
    default=USWEST,
)

birth_date = models.DateField(null=True, blank=False,)
sessions_played = models.IntegerField(null=False, blank=False, default='0',)
teamwork_commends = models.IntegerField(null=False, blank=False, default='0',)
communication_commends = models.IntegerField(null=False, blank=False, default='0',)
skill_commends = models.IntegerField(null=False, blank=False, default='0',)
positivity_commends = models.IntegerField(null=False, blank=False, default='0',)
```

**FORMS.PY**

```
 from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm, AuthenticationForm
from apps.api.models import Profile, Feedback
from django.forms import ModelForm

#form to create profile
#RegistrationForm VIEW must be created first as well as URl
class RegistrationForm(UserCreationForm):
first_name = forms.CharField(max_length=30, required = False, help_text='Optional.')
last_name = forms.CharField(max_length=30, required = False, help_text='Optional.')
email = forms.EmailField(max_length=254, required=True, help_text='Required. Enter a valid email address.')
birth_date = forms.DateField(help_text='Required. Format: YYYY-MM-DD')
#Class meta will dictate what the form uses for its fields
class Meta:
    model = User
    fields = (
            'username',
            'first_name',
        'last_name',
        'email',
            'birth_date',
        'password1',
        'password2',
    )



#Function to save form details
def save(self,commit=True):
    if commit:
        #Setting Commit to false,otherwise It will only save the fields existing in UserCreationForm
        user = super(RegistrationForm, self).save(commit=False)
        #Adding additional Fields that need to be saved
        #Cleaned data prevents SQL Injections
        user.first_name = self.cleaned_data['first_name']
        user.last_name = self.cleaned_data['last_name']
        user.email = self.cleaned_data['email']
        Profile.birth_date = self.cleaned_data['birth_date']
        user.save()

        return user

# User editing profile details
class EditProfileForm(RegistrationForm):
class Meta:
    model = User
    fields = [
        'email',
        'first_name',
        'last_name',
        'birth_date',
    ]
```

Comment: Please fix the indentation. You can manually add the profile's fields in your form, and update your save function accordingly. Retrieve the values from `cleaned_data`, update the profile with them. Also, why are you redeclaring `first_name`, `last_name`, and others? They already are in `UserCreationForm`.

Comment: In fact this is what you are doing. But instead of `Profile.birth_date =`, I think you should use `user.profile.birth_date =`.

Comment: You're right,I shouldn't be calling them,my mistake,thanks for that. :)
changing it to user.profile.birthdate still makes no difference though,when I submit my EditProfileForm the birth_date field is still unchanged.

Comment: You might need to save the profile as well, as it is another object: `user.profile. save()`

Comment: That worked!Thank you so much.